# Sending the exact same XML to a server - one works, one gets error?

Tags: c#, xml, http, networking, post

I have a server configured to receive XML files via POST, parse them, and display some info accordingly. The server works perfectly and has been tested extensively.

I have two clients for this server. In both, I have hardcoded some well-formed XML. When the first client sends its post message, the server responds perfectly.

When the second, sends it's post message, the server responds with an error (below).

This is despite both clients

- Running the same code
- Posting the same XML

Here is the code used to send the POST :

```
 public void SendPost(string xmlInfo)
        {
            ErrorHandler.Execute(() => {
                XMLHTTP objhttp = new XMLHTTP();
                objhttp.open("POST", Properties.Settings.Default.postpath, false, "", "");
                objhttp.send(xmlInfo);

                var x = XElement.Parse(objhttp.responseText);
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is not in the sent XML (it is hardcoded and exactly the same in both cases) and it is not on the Server as this will respond perfectly and has been tested a lot. What could be causing my problem ?

The error message is now :

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please
>   contact the system administrator.  If you are the system
>   administrator please click here to find
>   out more about this error.

Comment: the app on the server should have some log to see what happens, otherwise is just guessing.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Can you check the logs to find out more about the 500 error?

Comment: Load Balancing...how does it work ? You shld be having logs or Eventviewer

Comment: Added the error message, which is now slightly different!

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to validate your belief that both clients are "Posting the same XML". Also look at the headers.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe I have access to the logs ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is not in the sent XML (it is hardcoded and exactly the same in both cases) and it is not on the Server as this will respond perfectly and has been tested a lot.

If your server is responding with code 500 (which signals "internal error") then the problem almost certainly *is* in the server - or at least, there's probably *a* problem in the server.

You should have a look at the logs of the server receiving the data - I'd *hope* that any well-written server would dump diagnostics (e.g. exceptions) to the log on failure.

("Tested a lot" doesn't mean "has no conceivable failure modes"...)

Comment: @SimonKiely: You need to ask someone who *do* has access to the logs to see what's wrong. Basically it's a black box otherwise...